# Transaction is not working for File.Move() operation in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, transactions

**Scenario :** I have three folders in local system. I want to move the files from "Source 1" to "Source 2" (Its a one task in WCF Service 1) and then from "Source 2" to "Destination" (Its a another task in WCF Service 2). If any transaction failes, then file should be in "Source 1".

But what happening is, Service 2 is moving file from "Source 1" to "Source 2" successfully. and Service 1 is trying to move the same file from "Source 2" to "Destination" but it fails. So my file should be in "Source 1". but I am finding it in "Source 2".

Please help me in this. and tell me its possible or not in WCF.

**Code**
Client Code

```
ITransactionSupportService wsChannel = new ChannelFactory<ITransactionSupportService>("wsEndPoint").CreateChannel();
var result = wsChannel.FileMoveService1();
```

Service1 Code : Method FileMoveService1()

```
ITransactionSupport2Service svcMultipleSvcChanel = new ChannelFactory<ITransactionSupport2Service>("netPipeConfig").CreateChannel();
bool flag = svcMultipleSvcChanel.FileMoveService2();
if (File.Exists(@"D:\Transaction File Movement\Source 2\Trans.txt"))
{
   **throw new Exception("Test");**
   File.Copy(@"D:\Transaction File Movement\Source 2\Trans.txt", @"D:\Transaction File Movement\Destination\Trans.txt");
}
```

Service2 Code : Method FileMoveService2()

```
if (File.Exists(@"D:\Transaction File Movement\Source 1\Trans.txt"))
   File.Move(@"D:\Transaction File Movement\Source 1\Trans.txt", @"D:\Transaction File Movement\Source 2\Trans.txt");
   return true;
```

Thanks in advance
Nitish

Comment: **How** does it fail? is there an exception?

Comment: Yes Yuval Itzchaakov, I am throwing exception just before moving file from "Source 2" to "Destination" just for my testing purpose.

Comment: Add the exception to your question.

Comment: Hi Yuval Itzchaakov, I have added some code also. Please see it and help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File operations do not support transactions. You need to handle rollback manually.

You do that by enlist your file operation in the `TransactionScope`. It's done like this (not tested code, you have to complete it):

```
public class FileMover : IEnlistmentNotification
{
    private readonly string _source;
    private readonly string _destination;

    public FileMover(string source, string destination)
    {
        Transaction.Current.EnlistVolatile(this, EnlistmentOptions.None);
        _source = source;
        _destination = destination;

        File.Move(_source, _destination);
    }

    public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        enlistment.Done();
    }
    public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        enlistment.Done();
    }
    public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
    {
        preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
    }
    public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        File.Move(_destination, _source);
        enlistment.Done();
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification(v=vs.110).aspx